# Override default sort for ActiveDataProvider in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a lot of models using `created_time`. And I want all of the GridViews to show the models sorted by `created_time` DESC.

Right now I write something like this

```
$dataProvider = new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => MyModel::find(),
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => [
                'created_time' => SORT_DESC
            ]
        ],
    ]);
```

Instead of writing all of `sort` configuration I tried ways below but nothing works.

1. Using container

   ```
   \Yii::$container->set(\yii\data\ActiveDataProvider::class,
           [
       'sort' => [
           'defaultOrder' => [
               'created_time' => SORT_DESC
           ]
       ]
   ]);
   ```
2. Overriding the `sort` in extended class.

   ```
   class ActiveDataProvider extends \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider {

       public $sort = [
           'defaultOrder' => [
               'created_time' => SORT_DESC
           ]
       ];

    }
   ```
3. Overriding before `init()` in the extended class works, but it won't work if the instantiation tries to override again.

   ```
   class ActiveDataProvider extends \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider {
       public function init() {
           $this->sort = [
               'defaultOrder' => [
                   'created_time' => SORT_DESC
               ]
           ];
           parent::init();
       }

   }

   //but this won't work if I want to use the ascending
   $dataProvider = new \app\components\data\ActiveDataProvider([
       'query' => MyModel::find(),
       'sort' => [
           'defaultOrder' => [
               'created_time' => SORT_ASC
           ]
       ],
   ]);
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this for [yii\data\Sort](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sort.html) and not for [yii\data\ActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-activedataprovider.html). See the documentation to [$sort](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-basedataprovider.html#$sort-detail) property.

**1)** With container:

```
use Yii;

...

Yii::$container->set(\yii\data\Sort::className(),
    'defaultOrder' => [
        'created_time' => SORT_DESC,
    ],
]);
```

**2)** Overriding class:

```
class Sort extends yii\data\Sort
{
    public $defaultOrder' = [
        'created_time' => SORT_DESC,
    ];
}
```

Comment: sorry, my bad, it works. I have to use the `\yii\data\Sort` instead of `yii\data\Sort`

Comment: How to handle default sorting If some models don't have created_time ?

Answer (score 7):

To do this for a single GridView, you can add `'defaultOrder' => ['created_time' => SORT_DESC]` to the array that is accepted by `setSort()`:

```
    $dataProvider->setSort([
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            ...
        ],
        'defaultOrder' => ['created_time' => SORT_DESC]
    ]);
```

Comment: Yes, but he wants to set it globally for all GridViews.